# Constrain img to div and maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, image

I've tried everything I can find.

I'm trying to keep an image from overflowing outside the div that it is inside.

I've tried:

```
div.row #whoPic {
    object-fit: contain;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: auto;
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

...and many variations of each of those values.

I've also tried targeting all img's, as well as targeting very precisely.

Please help me out. Going nuts here.

Comment: are you using that entire block of css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

Answer (score 2):

In fact this question has been asked before. 
Here: [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container) 
Here: [Make an image width 100% of parent div, but not bigger than its own width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463664/make-an-image-width-100-of-parent-div-but-not-bigger-than-its-own-width) 
Here: [Contain an image within a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071830/contain-an-image-within-a-div) 
Here: [How do I fit an image (img) inside a div and keep the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394309/how-do-i-fit-an-image-img-inside-a-div-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Restrict the image with `max-width` and `max-height` both set to `100%`.

```css
.theContainer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.theContainer img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="theContainer">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
<h3> The original image size is 200x200 </h3>
<img src="https://placehold.it/200x200">
```

Comment: `<img>` does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: Does this work on other objects as well, such as iframes and forms? I have a form that is leaving its div as well, but not matter what I do, I can't get it to stay in there, or for the div to change its height when the window is smaller.

Comment: This method only works for images. I just tried it with forms and iframes and it didn't work for either.

Comment: @Rob `<img />` and `<img>` are equally valid. It's the difference of XHTML and HTML. Both are standards compliant.

Comment: @dougoftheabaci The question is tagged HTML, not XHTML. There has never been any HTML specification that has ever called for a closing slash on the `<img>` tag. Though allowed, because it's a void element, the specification states a closing slash means nothing, it does nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it.

Comment: (1) So you're suggesting no one ever says HTML as a catch-all for both? (2) It's both valid (part of the spec) and a common style convention. But that's alright.