# Using CSS ONLY to center images in a grid, constraining height, keeping aspect ratio

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a grid of images which are to display in a single row. The grid's height is not to exceed the height of the browser. Each image can my any height and any width.

The image must be vertically and horizontally centered in its container. If the image's height or width is bigger than its container, then the image should not overflow its bounds.

Is this possible?

There are many posts out there asking similar questions.

[Constrain img to div and maintain aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292380/constrain-img-to-div-and-maintain-aspect-ratio?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[CSS: How can I set image size relative to parent height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192892/css-how-can-i-set-image-size-relative-to-parent-height)

And so on. However none that I see are using flexbox.

```
<div class='grid-container'>
  <div class='grid'>
    <div class='col'>
      <div class='img-container'>
        <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/300x150'/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
      <div class='img-container'>
        <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/200x400'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/stljeff1/pen/MEWoPN

Here is a codepen showing what I'm trying to do

Why does `img {max-height: 100%; }` not do anything but `img { height: 150px; }` constrains the image?

**********Edit****************
as pointed out in comments below, I could use object-fit. The example cited Works in IE Edge, not IE 11.

Comment: height:100% needs a parent with a valid height. the cascad to inherit a valid height value to be calculated is lost from .grid which has no height. 100% of what ? parent container set at 200px or the window ? to inherit height + object-fit , you could have this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZNEYQ or https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrjyVv

Comment: yes, i did come across object-fit. is that cross browser compatible? I thought it broke in IE. There are polyfills, however, i'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: okay, do you want to use flex or any other display ? what is the maximum height you refer to : 200px or window's ?

Comment: max height is window, or a little less for padding

Comment: then you can use max-height:100vh only on img tag, and let the parent do their regular job without mastering heights. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZXEXGX ;) It works with IE11

Comment: Thats great. Perfect. The answer, then, is that the only way to get an image to constrain itself is to apply a max height that is fixed. Percentages are relative, not fixed. Using the Viewport height is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if you try to do this :

```
    img {
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/wrvqRv