# How to align navbar-brand with rest of links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I use an image along side a link, the navbar is getting bigger.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="..." /> // this is causing the problem 
             Me<span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a>Sample 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a>Sample 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The result is http://jsfiddle.net/6xzwdwfr/18/embedded/result/. But how do I make it so that it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/6xzwdwfr/21/embedded/result/?

Basically, I want to make sure that adding the image doesn't cause the navbar to enlarge.

I tried lessening some of the paddings and margins in the `nav*` classes, but it only made the matters worse.

How can I adjust it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove top and bottom paddings from .navbar-nav > li > a

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 0px 12px;
  margin: 12.5px 6px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. You can edit my fiddle and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to put your image in the navbar so it fit in and keep the ratio, you might take a look at this answered post :
[How do I fit an image (img) inside a div and keep the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394309/how-do-i-fit-an-image-img-inside-a-div-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

Try re-sizing the `<a>` that contains the image by adding the following code:

```
li.dropdown > a {
    height: 34px;
}
```

This way, the `<a>` element doesn't take up any more space than the `<img>` it contains. I tried it in your Fiddle and it worked.