# Image makes fix sized div larger

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I am trying to put an image into my Website. 
The image is in a div that hast got a fixed size. 
The Problem is that the image stretches the whole div
when I use auto height in CSS.

The Image fits into its div setting its height and width to 100%:

[image]

Now I would like to keep the Image unstretched. 
So I set the width 100% and the height as auto
as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394309/how-do-i-fit-an-image-img-inside-a-div-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio)
After setting that the image is in a layer under the section below 
but layers on the next part of the page.

[image]

here is the HTML Code I used:

```
<div class="section4">
        <section class="half">
            <div class="officePicContainer">
                <img src="officePic.jpg" alt="New Office of MEGO" class="officePic">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="half">


        </section>  
    </div>
```

And The CSS Code:

```
 .half {
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.half:first-child {


}
.half:last-child {
    background: #950049;

}
     .officePic {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

How can I resize the image and fitting into its parent div without stretching it? Is it still possible in CSS? Or is Java Script needed?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create div and, the background-size:cover css tag and set position: fixed

```
<div class="demo" style="background-image:url(example.png);background-size: cover; background-position:center center;"></div>
```

Comment: wait.. I did a mistake. your solution works fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: Without JS you have to give the div an fixed height and the Image won't be streched.

Comment: No problem, set my answer as solution to help other guys with the same question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div><img src="http://www.engineering.com/Portals/0/BlogFiles/swertel/heart-cloud.jpg" width=100% /></div>
```