# Fitting an image inside a <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit the buttons and the image inside the navbar div. What ends up happening is that the buttons end up within the `<div>`, but the image extends way beyond the `<div>`:

[image]

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

#navbar {
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 1%;
  height: 6%;
  background: black;
  padding: 0.25%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1%;
  margin-top: 0%; !important
}
#logo {
  width: auto;
}
.link-buttons {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <!-- navigation bar -->
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <!--  nav bar buttons -->
      <li id="logo"><span><img id="logo" src="logo-transparent.gif"/></span></li>
      <li class="link-buttons"><button>Join the team!</button></li>
      <li class="link-buttons"><button>Attend a class!</button></li>
      <li class="link-buttons"><button>Contact Us!</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- content -->
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: provided your js fiddle. thx

Comment: check out this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394309/how-do-i-fit-an-image-img-inside-a-div-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394309/how-do-i-fit-an-image-img-inside-a-div-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Comment: I think you need to mention a width and height to your logo...can you please provide a jsfiddle as Fiido said.

Comment: Do not use same id for multiple elements. "Id"s are mean to be used one per page.
<li id="logo"><span><img id="logo" src="logo-transparent.gif"/></span></li>
May be you should set a fixed height for the image. Set width: auto; height: 32px;  change the value to what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
  #logo {
    width: auto;
    height:100%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

see this.

```css
 .container-box {
    position:relative;
}
.container-box img {
      position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:5%;
 background-color:transparent !important;
}
.link-buttons {
  float: right;
  padding:8px 8px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-box">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: #000000">
     <li class="link-buttons"><button>Join the team!</button></li>
          <li class="link-buttons"><button>Attend a class!</button></li>
          <li class="link-buttons"><button>Contact Us!</button></li>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 120px; background-color: #ffffff"></div>
    <div class="image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s31.postimg.org/7t5144zsr/image.png" width="200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just specify the width/height in pixels/% that way the aspect ratio won't be tampered and the image will be placed inside the header.

so just go ahead with

```
#logo{
 width: 50px;
}
```

OR

```
#logo{
width:30%;
}
```

PS: The value of width must be changed as per your requirement.