# Background image fitted

Tags: html, css

I don't have code to showcase, but I am trying to have an img or background image fitted inside a container exactly and resizes when the screen gets resizes as well.
Can someone help please?

Edit: I specifically want the background to remain fitted in the div

```
<!-- Intro Section -->
<section class="success" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>intro</h2>
                <!--<hr class="star-light"> -->
                <br>

                <p>
                    text
                </p>

                 <p>
                   text 
                </p>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                    <i class="fa fa-download"></i> download
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End of intro section -->


#about{
```

}

Comment: CSS: `background-size:cover`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fit an image (img) inside a div and keep the aspect ratio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394309/how-do-i-fit-an-image-img-inside-a-div-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Comment: use `background-size:contain` see my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0):

use the `background-size:contain` property .

see snippet below. let me know if it works

```css
#container {
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  background:url("http://beerhold.it/579/300") no-repeat scroll center center / contain transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

more info :

`background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;`

i suggested to use `contain` and not `cover` because :

A. **Contain**

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

B. **Cover**

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area

so as it says in the documentation **( [info here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) )** , using `cover` doesn't resize the image if your container gets smaller than the `background-image` . but `contain` does exactly what you need.

if you want you can play with `cover` and `contain` to see the difference

to have both behaviors  ( stretch and resize ) you could use media Queries ( there are a number of ways to do this. this is just an example )

with CSS is the only thng you can do. i think :)

i used `@media only screen and (max-width: 579px) {` because `579px` is the width of the `img` in this example

see code snippet below or better see  **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d58zabar/)**

```css
#container {
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  background:url("http://beerhold.it/579/300") no-repeat scroll  center top transparent;
  background-size:cover;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 579px) {
#container {background-size:contain;}

}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: It Semi-worked, but not completely. I get to see all the image in the container, but it overflows to the padding area and does not cover all the container

Comment: well you could use `@media queries` . so when the `container` is bigger than the `background-image` you should use `cover` and when the `container` is smaller than the `background-image` you should use `cover`

Comment: I used both of them. They all get cropped when resizing the screen. Which media query?

Comment: that's impossible because , as you can see in my example and in the given documentation , with `background-size:contain` the image will never be cropped. it will resize to fit the window and keep it's aspect ratio. can you edit your original question with your relevant code ?

Comment: It is not cropped. The full size is out, but it overflows and its not contained in the container itself. From the right side is a white background and it does not stretch the image to fit the container exactly

Comment: that's why i said you should use media Query . i will edit my answer

Comment: I will test this and see. I am not very familiar with @media queries