# How can I keep an image from overflowing its container?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm working with Reactjs in a page... like a diary.
At the end of the page, there is an img that I'm trying to set inside the page but because of the size, it goes out of the page... I try to modify it with Css, but still not working. Can you help me please?

This is how the page looks:
[image]

This is how the html code looks:

```
<div className="notes__content">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Somer awesome title" className="notes__title-input" autoComplete="off"/>
            <textarea placeholder="What happened today?" className="notes__textarea"></textarea>
            <div className="notes__image">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4173624/pexels-photo-4173624.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="imagen"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is how I set the css:

```
    .notes__main-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.notes__appbar{
    align-items: center;
    background-color: $primary;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;   
}

.notes__content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.notes__title-input, .notes__textarea{
    border: none;

    &:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
}

.notes__title-input{
    color: $dark-grey;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.notes__textarea{
    border: none;
    color: $dark-grey;
    font-size: 20px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    resize: none;   
}

.notes__image{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px $dark-grey;
    height:  150px;
}
```

To be clear, what I want to do is to set the img to 150px so it can fit my page. Thank you for your help

Comment: try this it - .`notes__image img { width: 100%; }`

Comment: Well I'm using React js, so I have to use className... so I think that's the proper way

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394309/how-do-i-fit-an-image-img-inside-a-div-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that answer helped me to understand a little bit more about it... but it didn't worked... One of the answers I receive, solved my problem... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The className property is used in React. Is this a React application? If not, it needs to be revised to "class".

Also make sure your image does not overflow the bounds of the div. You can set strict width and height in the image by using the img tag's "width" and "height" properties. Or create a notes__image img declaration, like this:

```
.notes__image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using React js... thanks for the advice

Comment: Ok so your className declaration is correct, then. Try the .notes__image img CSS I showed you.

Comment: Setting height explicitly will result in stretching. I doubt that's desirable in a blog post.

Comment: Sure, I tried it but... what I want to do is to resize the img so it can fit my page... to set the img to 150 px

Comment: .notes__image img {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
    }

Comment: yes, it works... I guess I needed to specify the img into the css, thanks

Comment: Make sure the height and width, if explicitly declared, are proportional to the original size of the image to prevent stretching. Let me know if you have any other problems!

Answer (score 2):

Images don't magically shrink to fit their containers. You need to tell them to do so:

```
.notes__image img {
  max-width: 100%; /* <-- here's your huckleberry */
}
```

You don't want to use the `width` property as that'll stretch images beyond their native size, and you don't want to set height as that will goof up aspect ratio.

Here I've converted `className` to `class` for demonstration purposes. If you view the fullscreen demo and shrink the window size you can see it in action.

```css
.notes__main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.notes__appbar {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: $primary;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}

.notes__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.notes__title-input,
.notes__textarea {
  border: none;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}

.notes__title-input {
  color: $dark-grey;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.notes__textarea {
  border: none;
  color: $dark-grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  resize: none;
}

.notes__image {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px $dark-grey;
  height: 150px;
}
.notes__image img {
  max-width: 100%; /* <-- here's your huckleberry */
}
```

```html
<div class="notes__content">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Somer awesome title" class="notes__title-input" autoComplete="off" />
  <textarea placeholder="What happened today?" class="notes__textarea"></textarea>
  <div class="notes__image">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4173624/pexels-photo-4173624.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="imagen" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another div inside `notes__image` div. Lets call it `notes__image__inner` with a div wrapper.

```
<div className="notes__content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Somer awesome title" className="notes__title-input" autoComplete="off"/>
        <textarea placeholder="What happened today?" className="notes__textarea"></textarea>
        <div className="notes__image">
          <div className="notes__inner__image">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4173624/pexels-photo-4173624.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="imagen"/>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Update the `notes__image` and `img` CSS with this:

```
.notes__image {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px $dark-grey;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.notes__inner__image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.notes__inner__image img {
   width: 100%;
   position: static;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried it but it cut the img... so that´s not the answer I'm looking

Comment: You can remove image `height` and `width` for origin image ratio-